# Most efficient way to perform large dot/tensor dot products while only keeping diagonal entries

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, tensordot

I'm trying to figure out a way to use numpy to perform the following algebra in the most time-efficient way possible:

Given a 3D matrix/tensor, `A`, with shape `(n, m, p)` and a 2D matrix/tensor, `B`, with shape `(n, p)`, calculate `C_ij = sum_over_k (A_ijk * B_ik)`, where the resulting matrix `C` would have dimension (n, m).

I've tried two ways to do this. One is to loop through the first dimension, and calculate a regular dot product each time.
The other method is to use `np.tensordot(A, B.T)` to calculate a result with shape `(n, m, n)`, and then take the diagonal elements along 1st and 3rd dimension. Both methods are shown below.

First method:

```
C = np.zeros((n,m))

for i in range(n):

  C[i] = np.dot(A[i], B[i])
```

Second method:

```
C = np.diagonal(np.tensordot(A, B.T, axes = 1), axis1=0, axis2=2).T
```

However, because n is a very large number, the loop over n in the first method is costing a lot of time. The second method calculates too many unnecessary entries to obtain that huge `(n, m, n)`matrix, and is also costing too much time, I'm wondering if there's any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define 2 arrays:

```
In [168]: A = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4); B = np.arange(2*4).reshape(2,4)
```

Your iterative approach:

```
In [169]: [np.dot(a,b) for a,b in zip(A,B)]                                                                  
Out[169]: [array([14, 38, 62]), array([302, 390, 478])]
```

The `einsum` practically writes itself from your `C_ij = sum_over_k (A_ijk * B_ik)`:

```
In [170]: np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', A, B)                                                                      
Out[170]: 
array([[ 14,  38,  62],
       [302, 390, 478]])
```

`@`, `matmul`, was added to perform batch `dot` products; here the `i` dimension is the batch one.  Since it uses the last of `A` and 2nd to the last of `B` for the `dot` summation, we have to temporarily expand `B` to `(2,4,1)`:

```
In [171]: A@B[...,None]                                                                                      
Out[171]: 
array([[[ 14],
        [ 38],
        [ 62]],

       [[302],
        [390],
        [478]]])
In [172]: (A@B[...,None])[...,0]                                                                             
Out[172]: 
array([[ 14,  38,  62],
       [302, 390, 478]])
```

Typically `matmul` is fastest, since it passes the task to BLAS like code.

Answer (score 0):

here is my implementation:

```
B = np.expand_dims(B, axis=1)
E = A * B
E = np.sum(E, axis=-1)
```

Check :

```
import numpy as np
n, m, p = 2, 2, 2
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.randint(1, 10, (n, m, p))
B = np.random.randint(1, 10, (n, p))

C = np.diagonal(np.tensordot(A, B.T, axes = 1), axis1=0, axis2=2).T

# from here is my implementation
B = np.expand_dims(B, axis=1)
E = A * B
E = np.sum(E, axis=-1)

print(np.array_equal(C, E))

True
```

use the `np.expand_dims()` to add a new dimension. 
And use the broadcast multiply. Finally, sum along the third dimension.

Thanks check code from [user3483203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3483203/user3483203)